# How to serve image assets from an Engine in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble getting image assets in my engine to render inside the host app.

My host app is capable of grabbing css and javascript from then engine thanks to code like this in the `view/layout/application.html.erb` file:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'my_engine/application', :media => 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'my_engine/application' %>
```

However, I don't know of a similar method for including the images from my engine.  Any ideas on how I can get the engine's image files to render in the host app?

Edit:

In my engine's engine.rb file, I've added the images directory to the app's directory like this:

```
initializer :assets do |config|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "images", "my_engine", "some_subdirectory")
end
```

and the view has an image tag that looks like this:

```
<%= image_tag "/my_engine/some_subdirectory/picture.png" %>
```

but my server logs, I see this:

```
Started GET "/assets/some_subdirectory/picture.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 20:11:38 -0500
Served asset /some_subdirectory/picture.png - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/some_subdirectory/picture.png"):
```

Comment: Did you add your engine's asset path to `config.assets.paths`? If so, what isn't working when you use an appropriately namespaced `image_tag` helper?

Comment: How are you referencing your images? You need to use <%= image_tag('image') %> rather than <img src="image">. Similar in your css files, need image_tag().

Comment: Good questions.  I've updated my post to address them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this at all because Rails does it *for you*:

```
initializer :assets do |config|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "images", "my_engine", "some_subdirectory")
end
```

Instead, you can reference the images exactly the same way as you would as if they were in the application:

```
<%= image_tag "your_image.jpg" %>
```

I'm assuming here that `your_image.jpg` is at `/app/assets/images/your_image.jpg` within your engine. If it's in a subdirectory, then:

```
<%= image_tag "subdirectory/your_image.jpg" %>
```

There's no need to include the name of your engine in the path unless the file is at some place like `app/assets/images/your_engine/your_image.jpg`, in which case:

```
<%= image_tag "your_engine/your_image.jpg" %>
```

Would be the correct way to do this.

[The Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) contains more useful information about engines too.

Comment: Can you point out what is incorrect about the approach I've outlined above (i.e. where I add the images path to the Apps' assets path and provide a namespaced image_tag)?

Comment: @BenDowney: There is no reason at all to do that when Rails already provides you a way to access the images for an engine from within an application.

Comment: Also make sure your names of the images in the engine do not clash, because names in the rails assets will take precedence over the engine (rails first searches in its own assets, then through all the engines --this allows you to overrule images if needed). So imho it is best to place your images in a subfolder in the engine, so they surely will not clash by accident.

Comment: @nathanvda I agree about using the subfolder - and that is what is says in the engine guide: Because this engine is going to be namespaced, its assets should be too. That is an interesting point you make about intentionally overriding the base app's images with the engine.